# Program crashes if returned value is null

Tags: c#, mysql, mono

i am trying to retrieve some data from mysql(c#,mono), the problem is that if the returned value is null the program crashes, i know it has to do something with the returned null value, because if i want to retrieve something that is in the database it works,can anyone help me with this?

The code:

```
MySqlConnection dbcon;
dbcon = new MySqlConnection(conString);
try
{
    dbcon.Open();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine("MySQL Database Connection Problem !!!");

}

//reading data from mysql   
MySqlCommand dbcmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, dbcon);

MySqlDataReader reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();

while(reader.Read()){

    txtFirstname.Text = reader["first_name"].ToString();
    txtLastname.Text  = reader["last_name"].ToString();
    imgUser.File      = path+reader["photo"].ToString();
    expDate           = reader["expiration_datetime"].ToString();
    usrName           = reader["username"].ToString();

}

dbcon.Close();
```

Comment: Which value is returning null?

Comment: I don't see any instruction here that could return null. The DbDataReader indexer is supposed to return `DBNull.Value`, not null.

Comment: What exception do you get? Change the `catch` block to `catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }` and tell us what it says

Comment: Also, you should put the connection, command, and DataReader into `using` blocks.

Comment: it returns something like this:
<hr>
<pre><code>
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentException: Stream is not a valid .resources file, magic=0x6d783f3c
  at System.Resources.ResourceReader.ReadHeaders () [0x00000] 
  at System.Resources.ResourceReader..ctor (System.IO.Stream stream) [0x00000] 
  at System.Resources.ResourceSet..ctor (System.IO.Stream stream) [0x00000] 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke (object,object[])
 
</code>

Comment: Are you reading from an embedded resource...that's what the exception message is about...?

Comment: Exceptions are helpful, they tell you the code line where the exception was thrown. Which line in the posted code threw the exception ?

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the `ToString` method on the objects returned by MySQL.

If MySQL returns `null`, you'll call the `ToString` method on a `null` object, giving a `NullReferenceException`.

Assuming that the SQL is actually returning strings (not numbers or dates), you can simply cast to a string, like this:  `(string)reader["username"]`.
If the SQL is returning non-string datatypes, you can call `Convert.ToString(reader["username"])`.

Both of these will result in `null` if MySQL returns `null`.

If you want MySQL `null`s to result in something other than `null`, use the null coalescing operator, like this: `Convert.ToString(reader["username"]) ?? "It's Null!"`.

Comment: `reader["columnName"]` should never return null, it should return `DBNull.Value`. Perhaps it's a bug in the MySQL provider...

Comment: It's not the only adapter that does that unfortunately. Some versions of the Oracle adapter (the one by Oracle, not the in-built Microsoft one) do that as well.

Answer (score 1):

For instance, let's imagine your "first_name" is null at database; `reader["first_name"]` will return `null` and it doesn't have a `.ToString()` method, so your code fails.

Below, I changed way you get that files; I try to cast it to string and, if I got a `null` value, I use that `??` (null-coalescing operator) to return an empty string.

```
txtFirstname.Text = reader["first_name"  ] as string ?? "";
txtLastname.Text  = reader["last_name"   ] as string ?? "";
imgUser.File      = path + reader["photo"] as string ?? "";
expDate           = reader["expiration_datetime"] as string ?? "";
usrName           = reader["username"] as string ?? "";
```

HTH

Comment: tanx for the answers, but still no difference. I am using this in a "FocusOutEvent" so, when i want to retrieve someones information(i use barcode scanner) that is in the mysql, it returns with information, but when the person is not in the database, it crashes. simply after scanning the barcode i hit tab, thats when it crashes.

Comment: what line exactly that problem occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the exception in your comment, it looks like you have a completely different problem somewhere else.

I would guess that you're reading a `.resources` file and generating a filename from the SQL query.  If so, `null`s might cause you to generate an incorrect filename.

You need to debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

so i guess it will help to post the whole code, here it is. i am just trying to activate an account in ldap, by scanning the barcode which is printed on a card. i also retrieve information about the user of that account, from mysql database.

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using Gtk;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using Novell.Directory.Ldap;
```

public partial class MainWindow: Gtk.Window
{
    public MainWindow (): base (Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
    {
        Build ();
    }

`protected void OnDeleteEvent (object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
{
    Application.Quit ();
    a.RetVal = true;
}

protected virtual void OnEntry1FocusOutEvent (object o, Gtk.FocusOutEventArgs args)
{
    string conString = "server=localhost;database=ldap;User ID=someid;password=somepassword;";
    string sql = String.Format("Select * From user where barcode='{0}'",txtBarcode.Text);
    string path = "/home/path/to/project/Photo/";
    string expDate = "";
    string usrName = "";
    //creating connection with database
    MySqlConnection dbcon;
    dbcon = new MySqlConnection(conString);
    try

    {

        dbcon.Open();

    }

    catch (Exception ex)

    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());

        //Console.WriteLine("MySQL Database Connection Problem !!!");

    }
    //reading data from mysql
    MySqlCommand dbcmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, dbcon);

    MySqlDataReader reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();

    while(reader.Read()){


        txtFirstname.Text = Convert.ToString(reader["first_name"]);
        txtLastname.Text  = Convert.ToString(reader["last_name"]);
        imgUser.File      = path+Convert.ToString(reader["photo"]);
        expDate           = Convert.ToString(reader["expiration_datetime"]);
        usrName           = Convert.ToString(reader["username"]);

        }

    dbcon.Close();

    //changeing time from sting to datetime
    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(expDate);
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    txtStatus.Text = dt.ToString();
    //checking if the account has expired
    if(dt > now){
        //connecting with ldap server
        string server = "ip of the server";
        string dn = "cn=Manager,dc=itc";
        string up = "password";
        string dn1 = "uid="+usrName+",ou=people,dc=itc";

        // Create a new LdapConnection instance
        LdapConnection connl = new LdapConnection();

        // Connect to the server
        connl.Connect(server, 389);

        //Bind
        connl.Bind(dn,up);

        //Modify user in ldap entry
        ArrayList modList = new ArrayList();
        LdapAttribute attribute;
        //Replace the value of loginshell attribute
        attribute = new LdapAttribute( "loginShell", "/bin/sh");
        modList.Add( new LdapModification(LdapModification.REPLACE, attribute));

        LdapModification[] mods = new LdapModification[modList.Count];  
        //Type mtype=Type.GetType("Novell.Directory.LdapModification");
        mods = (LdapModification[])modList.ToArray(typeof(LdapModification));

        //Modify the entry in the directory
        connl.Modify ( dn1, mods );
        txtStatus.Text="Account Activated!";
        // Disconnect from server
        connl.Disconnect();
    }else{
        txtStatus.Text="Account Expired!";

    }
}`

}